# Visual Studio Community 2017 - Google Vision API - Can't find my error

Tags: .net, visual-studio, google-compute-engine, google-vision

I'm currently on an internship, and my project is to automate a drone, to make it recognize free parking spots or used parking spots. 
For that, I'm using the Google Vision API with Visual Studios Community 2017.

I already made all the " Before beginning " steps on Google Cloud Platform ( Create project, enable billing, get the Compute Engine Machine, and all these stuff ), I connected my Cloud Platform to Visual Studios, and Installed the packages in my project with the command line " Install-Packages Google.Cloud.Vision.V1 -Pre " in the Packet Manager.

I wrote this code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;

namespace WinImageRecognize
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
        // Load image file into memory
        var image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile("C:/Users/Stian/Pictures/Internship/car.jpg");
        // Does label detection on the image file
        var response = client.DetectLabels(image);


        textBox1.Text = "";

        foreach ( var annotation in response)
        {
            if (annotation.Description != null)
            {
                textBox1.Text += annotation.Description + "\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
   }
}
```

This code opens me my WindowsForm, looking like this : [Car parked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7QPo.jpg)

But when I run the application ( No errors ), and clic on the button, nothing happens !

And I can't fix my error ...

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot !